# Undefined is not a function with a combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-ui, undefined

I have got the Uncaught TypeError: `undefined is not a function in this line`

```
$('.for_checkbox select').combobox();
```

What does it mean? The combobox is filled correctly. What is wrong?

Comment: means you did not include the code for combobox.

Comment: make sure your selector string `.for_checkbox select` is actually retreiving an element, are you sure you didn't mean `.for_combobox select` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure all of those lines i provide appear in your html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="easyui/themes/icon.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="easyui/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

That must be the only reason it fails, except for 1 other.
Please be sure that `$('.for_checkbox select')` returns an element and not an empty array.
You can do it by opening your web application in Chrome/Firefox, Hit F12 and go to Console.
Inside the console, paste `$('.for_checkbox select')` and hit enter.
If the result is `[]`, that means that the element could not be found and that is the issue, otherwise, the import line codes are missing.

Links for import + documentation can be found [HERE](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually sure if jQuery UI's autocomplete set includes combobox(). Maybe that is just a custom demo they had on their site. I had to copy their source code into mine (combobox.js for the jQuery extension, and their CSS for it into my CSS file), and that is the only way I could get it to work.